# How to make a language pack for a VB.Net application

Tags: vb.net, localization, internationalization

I am making a web browser made in VB.Net, and I do have people using it from around the world, but I don't think all of them can understand everything it can do. Does anyone know how to create a sort of language pack that users can change the language of every label on the form? The only way I can think of is editing all the labels to another language, then publishing the application again, but that is a lot of work because I do use a lot of labels... any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking to do is called "localization." While localization itself is not a difficult topic to understand, depending on the complexity of your application, and the number and diversity of languages you want to support, it can become a rather involved task.

The general concept behind localizing an application is separating translatable elements (like all of the strings in your buttons, labels, and menus, or any images containing words) from the application itself, and storing them as resources which can then be chosen appropriately based on user preference or region, and then loaded into the application dynamically. There are a vast number of ways to accomplish this, and which you choose is entirely up to you, and how much effort you're willing to support. Techniques can range from loading strings from text files, storing and retrieving resources from a database, to using .NET's built-in localization functionality which stores assets in external resource files.

Localization as a topic is incredibly broad, so there is no single method that can be discussed without first knowing your specific goals and constraints. Your best plan of action is to start researching, and find a technique which seems most suitable for your project.

[Google: ".net localization"](http://www.google.com/#q=.net+localization)